# I am making squash bisque it calls for 1 cup of flour can I use 1 to 1 instead?

Tags: soup

The recipe calls for. 5 cups diced butternut squash,
1 cup of butter,
5 cups chicken broth
1 cup half and half
1 cup regular flour
Spices

Comment: Welcome! Could you please explain what “1 to 1” means?

Comment: A cup a flour?  Are you certain?

Comment: @moscafj they also use a cup of butter. I suppose the recipe includes making a roux out of the two, which is actually on the low side for flour. And if it is a darkish roux, the six cups of liquid will make a thick soup, but not pudding-thick.

Comment: @Stephie: it’s a prepackaged gluten free flour replacement

Comment: 1 cup flour and 1 cup butter to 5 cups broth sounds like a terrible recipe.  That's WAY too much roux for that much soup.  K Connor, flour replacements aside, I advise you to get a different recipe.

Comment: @rumtscho...I'm with Fuzzy on this one...

Comment: @FuzzyChef a cup of flour is only 120 g, while 6 cups of liquid are almost 1500 g. In the worst case, if the roux is not darkened at all, this is still thinner than a standard bechamel (1:10 flour to liquid) - if you take a spoon out of it, any excess should flow out of the spoon, not stay like a pudding. If it gets darkened to maybe hazelnut brown, it becomes even thinner, and if it is made super dark, it will be quite thin. And this is without accounting for water released from the squash. There may be people who don't like to eat soups in this texture range, but I personally find them OK.

Comment: Rumtscho: I'm speaking based on experience.  You're playing with numbers.

Comment: I'm used to weighing but that sounds like a little too much butter for a roux.  It sounds too thick for me, but a bisque is generally fairly thick. OTOH @rumtscho comparing bechamel to soup seems like a stretch

Comment: @KConnor, as you can see this has led to a bit of discussion, so we're clearly interested.  We could make  more progress with the whole recipe (e.g. a link) and with you saying what you mean by "1 to 1"  It's already 1:1 butter:flour, but something like 1:6 flour:liquid so it's hard to see how you'd like to modify it.  As it's unclear we may end up having to close an interesting question

Comment: 'comparing bechamel to soup seems like a stretch' How come, when they are saying the soup is *thinner* than a bechamel?